# How to define new events for spree promotions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I've been reading a almost everything I find about Spree promotions but i didn't find the way to define a new trigger for promotions.

I only find how to define actions and rules but nothing about defining events. I already know that it uses ActiveSupport::Notifications but i can't find the way to get through this.

[image: promotion event trigger select]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit of a tough one.  The first thing you'll need to do is fire an event when your condition occurs.  [fire_event](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.3/core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/common.rb#L18-L20) in the common controller helpers delegates that to ActiveSupport::Notification.

Then you'll need to decorate Spree::Promotion to add a new Activator like this [code which adds the coupon code activator](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.3/core/app/models/spree/promotion.rb#L6).

[This code](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.3/core/lib/spree/core/engine.rb#L10-L16) subscribes to the spree.* events and will fire the appropriate event based on the activator.  It calls the activate method on the appropriate class which you'll need to override in your decorated promotion.  The [default promotion activate does this](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.3/core/app/models/spree/promotion.rb#L39-L55), so you'll need to extend that code to do whatever you'd like on your event.

Hope that gives you somewhere to get started.

Comment: Cool, Was wondering how to do that, though I have no immediate need, you never know.

Comment: It worked perfectly and was simpler than I thought. Thank you!